# Android how to add the @ sign as text

Tags: android, text

hi I'm just creating a header for a app that uses twitter and just wanting to know how to show the @ as text i put it in a string and it doesn't like it

```
<string name="twit">@evosdfresh</string>
```

then i call this string it doesn't work if i remove the @ it works so its the @ thats throwing it off

Comment: My code works with an @ sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the @ as the first character of the string, then you need to escape it with a backslash, e.g.

```
<string name="twit">\@evosdfresh</string>
```

If it's in the middle of the string you don't need the backslash.

Comment: This worked thanks it won't let you preview it in the graphic layout editor but when i run it on the device it worked

Answer (score 3):

Try replacing the @ char with its utf-8 xml decimal representation: `&#64;`

EDIT: given the xml entity does not work, use the unicode definition: `\u0040`

Answer (score 0):

My idea is to replace it with an `&#64;`. Tell me if it works, I'd be interested to know, too ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try @ instead of @. If that doesn't work, you could also try escaping it, with 2 @'s instead of 1, or a backslash before it. @@evosdfresh or \@evosdfresh

Comment: these don't work i think its because the @ symbol thinks it s looking for a resource rather than just been text